# Nginx - Serving images without extensions

Tags: php, nginx, centos

So I moved from a cPanel to a CentOS server and all the files were loading fine. When moving I noticed I couldn't serve up images without an extension, for example:

domain.com/uploads/avatars/avatar_5.?dateline=1501944732
But in cPanel it's perfectly fine. I've been tampering around with the Nginx for the last few hours editing the default.cnf and what-not. Any ideas?

Edit: The current error being displayed is "404 Not Found"

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  domain;

# note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
server_tokens off;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
rewrite ^/forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forumdisplay.php?fid=$1;
    rewrite ^/forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2;
    rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1;
    rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2;
    rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost;
    rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest;
    rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest;
    rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost;
    rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2;
    rewrite ^/post-([0-9]+)\.html$ /showthread.php?pid=$1;
    rewrite ^/announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ /announcements.php?aid=$1;
    rewrite ^/user-([0-9]+)\.html$ /member.php?action=profile&uid=$1;
    rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ /calendar.php?calendar=$1;
    rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)\.html$ /calendar.php?action=yearview&calendar=$1&year=$2;
    rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ /calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3;
    rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ /calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4;
    rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ /calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2;
    rewrite ^/event-([0-9]+)\.html$ /calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /(upload/avatars) {
    allow all;
}
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|ico|xml)$ {
    access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           360d;
        }
}
```

I also have the original configuration if I need to revert.

.htaccess from the old cPanel (Apache)

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on

# Some hosts require RewriteBase to make RewriteRules work.
RewriteBase /

# Google SEO workaround for search.php highlights:
# Make this rule the first rewrite rule in your .htaccess!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ http://realforums.net/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]

# Google SEO Sitemap:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^sitemap\-([^./]+)\.xml$ misc.php?google_seo_sitemap=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

#
# If mod_security is enabled, attempt to disable it.
# - Note, this will work on the majority of hosts but on
#   MediaTemple, it is known to cause random Internal Server
#   errors. For MediaTemple, please remove the block below
#
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.
    SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

#
# MyBB "search engine friendly" URL rewrites
# - Note, for these to work with MyBB please make sure you have
#   the setting enabled in the Admin CP and you have this file
#   named .htaccess
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ announcements.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^user-([0-9]+)\.html$ member.php?action=profile&uid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^event-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1 [L,QSA]

    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#
# If Apache is compiled with built in mod_deflade/GZIP support
# then GZIP Javascript, CSS, HTML and XML so they're sent to
# the client faster.
#
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/html application/xhtml+xml text/xml application/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/json application/manifest+json application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/font-sfnt application/font-woff application/font-woff2 image/svg+xml image/x-icon
</IfModule>

# Note: You are able to choose a different name in the Admin CP. If you've done that you need to change it here too
<Files "error.log">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on

# Some hosts require RewriteBase to make RewriteRules work.
RewriteBase /

# Google SEO workaround for search.php highlights:
# Make this rule the first rewrite rule in your .htaccess!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ http://realforums.net/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]

# Google SEO Sitemap:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^sitemap\-([^./]+)\.xml$ misc.php?google_seo_sitemap=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

#
# If mod_security is enabled, attempt to disable it.
# - Note, this will work on the majority of hosts but on
#   MediaTemple, it is known to cause random Internal Server
#   errors. For MediaTemple, please remove the block below
#
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.
    SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

#
# MyBB "search engine friendly" URL rewrites
# - Note, for these to work with MyBB please make sure you have
#   the setting enabled in the Admin CP and you have this file
#   named .htaccess
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ announcements.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^user-([0-9]+)\.html$ member.php?action=profile&uid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^event-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1 [L,QSA]

    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#
# If Apache is compiled with built in mod_deflade/GZIP support
# then GZIP Javascript, CSS, HTML and XML so they're sent to
# the client faster.
#
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/html application/xhtml+xml text/xml application/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/json application/manifest+json application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/font-sfnt application/font-woff application/font-woff2 image/svg+xml image/x-icon
</IfModule>

# Note: You are able to choose a different name in the Admin CP. If you've done that you need to change it here too
<Files "error.log">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

I replaced Apache's .htaccess with Nginx's:

```
# Note: You are able to choose a different name in the Admin CP. If you've done that you need to change it here too
location ~ /error.log 
{ 
    deny all; 
}

# Note: You are able to rename the admin directory. If you've done that, you need to change it here too
location /admin/backups {
    deny all;
}

 # Google SEO workaround for search.php highlights:
  # Make this rule the first rewrite rule in your .htaccess!
  rewrite ^/MyBB/([^&]*)&(.*)$ http://yoursite/MyBB/$1?$2 permanent;

  # Google SEO Sitemap:
  rewrite ^/MyBB/((?i)sitemap-([^./]+)\.xml)$ /MyBB/misc.php?google_seo_sitemap=$2;
rewrite ^/forum-([0-9]+).html$ /forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 last;
rewrite ^/forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+).html$ /forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 last;
rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+).html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1 last;
rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+).html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 last;
rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost last;
rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest last;
rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest last;
rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-newpost.html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost last;
rewrite ^/thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+).html$ /showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 last;
rewrite ^/post-([0-9]+).html$ /showthread.php?pid=$1 last;
rewrite ^/announcement-([0-9]+).html$ /announcements.php?aid=$1 last;
rewrite ^/user-([0-9]+).html$ /member.php?action=profile&uid=$1 last;
rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+).html$ /calendar.php?calendar=$1 last;
rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+).html$ /calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3 last;
rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+).html$ /calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4 last;
rewrite ^/calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+).html$ /calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2 last;
rewrite ^/event-([0-9]+).html$ /calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1 last;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default nginx will add a `content-type` based on the extension. But in your case when the extension is missing it will miss adding the content type. So you would need to add one yourself

```
location ~ /(upload/avatars) {
    allow all;
    add_header Content-Type image/png;
}
```

If it stores png or `image/jpeg`

**Edit-1**

It seems you should be setting the `default_type` directive

```
location ~ /(upload/avatars) {
    allow all;
    default_type image/png;
}
```

**Edit-2**

To get rid of `.` at the end and still server the file use

```
location /uploads/avatars/ {
   default_type image/png;
   try_files $uri @without-dot;
}

location @without-dot {
  rewrite ^/(.*)\.$ /$1;
}
```

**Edit-3**

To get rid of `.` at the end and still server the file change the existing location block

```
location ~ /(upload/avatars) {
   allow all;
   default_type image/png;
   try_files $uri @without-dot;
}

location @without-dot {
  rewrite ^/(.*)\.$ /$1;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152951/discussion-on-answer-by-tarun-lalwani-nginx-serving-images-without-extensions). If you are still having a problem, update your question with the relevant information.

Comment: @CodyGray, i guess one cannot join chat if < 20 reputation?

Comment: The automatic move of comments to chat grants the users involved that privilege, regardless of their reputation. They won't be able to chat anywhere else, but they can chat in this room.